# Can't delete data in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

When I try to delete data in SQL Server 2008 , I get the following error.

> Msg 8630, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Internal Query Processor Error: The query processor encountered an unexpected error during execution.

My query is ..

```
delete STOCK 
where Shop_CODE = '101001' 
  and REF_DOC_NO = '80080001' 
  and DOC_TYPE = '21'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please refer to KB978190: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/978190

Answer (score 0):

Usually internal errors occurs when there is something wrong with the core of sql server, try to update to the latest service pack or reinstall the sql server

Answer (score 0):

```
delete FROM STOCK 
where Shop_CODE = '101001' and REF_DOC_NO = '80080001' and DOC_TYPE = '21'
```

Comment: @ Rohit Chaudhari ,thank for answer my question. But your query is not work for me. It is strange because other document number is OK. But this ref_doc_number'80080001' is fail when delete.

Comment: No, this is **not** the problem - the `FROM` keyword in a `DELETE` statement is **optional** (as a quick peek at the [official MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx)) easily shows....

Comment: @dragullar can you provide full error message there may be FOREIGN KEY issue

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen when there is a DATE or DATETIME field in the row you are trying to delete that contains invalid data.

For example, I have a DATETIME field with this value, which is invalid:

2014-09-27 00:00:00.003

In the past I have been able to NULL the invalid date and delete the row - it has worked for me in the past but not this time.  If I find another solution i'll try to post it here.

Comment: How can a `DATETIME` field *contain* an invalid value?